# Why doesn't boolean cut?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, boolean-modifier

When I cut my object it doesn't cut it, all it does is make an outline of the cylinder:

[image]

[image]

I have looked up videos and stuff, but none has yet explained why this is happening.
Does someone know why?

Answer (score 2):

The modifier is currently in error. This is illustrated by its red icon (marked red in the screenshot below). It's in error, because its *Object* field (marked blue) is empty. You need to set the object you want to perform the Boolean with in that field.

[image: Modifier]

Once you set the object, its icon will turn white, and you should be able to verify that it is working by hiding the boolean object.

---

If one of the objects involved in the operation is not manifold (fully closed, can hold water), then enable *Hole Tolerant* under *Solver Options*.